# Drag element from toolbar to Raphael canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, raphael

I want to have a toolbar of elements that I can drag only onto my Raphael canvas. Then, once it is in the canvas, it can be moved around anywhere inside the canvas. I'm not sure if I should use jQuery first, to make the toolbar elements draggable, and then once dropped into the Raphael canvas, use Raphael draggable method to be able to drag it around? My problem is how do I create the Raphael draggable once the element is dropped on the canvas?

I basically have my toolbar on the left of the page and my canvas on the right

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4 l3" id="toolBar"> 
        <!-- Note that "m4 l3" was added -->   
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m8 l9"> 
        <!-- Note that "m8 l9" was added -->
        <div id="mapImageDiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <span class="flow-text"></span>
            <svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1600 1000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin">
                <!--xMidYMin-->
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button style="display: none;" id="imageBtn" value={{map.image}}></button>
</div>
```

```js
var source = "data:image;base64," + $('#imageBtn').val();
var s = Raphael("svg", "100%", "100%");
var img = s.image(source, 0, 0, "100%", "100%");

var bigCircle = s.circle(450, 400, 10);
bigCircle.attr({
    fill: "#bada55",
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 3
});
```

Comment: Doesn't jquery drag have a callback where you can call a function to add the Raphael draggable method if thats what you are after ?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something along those lines. However, the problem is how do you change an html element to a raphael one?

Comment: Not sure why you would have to. You jquery drag on the html, then when its dropped, you add a Raph dragger to the svg paper/canvas.

Comment: Yes, but how to get the right coordinates according to the canvas to draw the raphael shape on?

Comment: If you can get a minimal testing example up on a jsfiddle or similar it would be useful, you could probably convert screen coordinates.